# Filtering unread inbox notifications only displays items that are unread in the summary list and not all unread items

Tags: feature-request, bug, global-inbox

I currently have 2 inbox notifications marked as unread. One is a relatively recent notification (yesterday) and the other is a relatively low priority item that has been sitting around since 2022-12-16 14:44:21Z. Both are things I will eventually want/need to follow up with.

Unfortunately, despite having two unread messages (as indicated by the red "2" indicator badge), when I filter my inbox for unread notifications only I only see one of the unread notifications (the one from yesterday):

[image]

I was able to find the other unread notification in my [full inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox) (currently on page 6):

[image]

---

I assume that the reason it's not displayed in the on-site inbox is because it's older than the oldest notification in the list (2022-12-17 04:30:41Z [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzDAV.png)) and the unread filter is a programmatic filter on the visible inbox items and not a separate request for the top N unread inbox items.

I find this behaviour a bit confusing, in that it left me wondering where the other unread item was and how I could easily find it.

Would it be possible to show all of my unread inbox items in the site inbox and/or provide a way to filter the [full inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox) for unread messages so that I don't have to search through each page in the full inbox for unread items?

Comment: I consider this as a bug, as the obvious expected behavior when filtering by unread items is, well, seeing all the unread items.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it - those are actually two separate issues (we're tracking them already). The first one, in inbox popup, is caused by the filter not loading all of the unread notifications rather than just filtering what's already loaded (the top 50 messages). The second issue (global inbox) is caused by the SE inbox not having access to all of the notifications (i.e. teams) and it's more complex to address. While this does not immediately solve your issue, I hope the explanation helps!

Comment: @marrados Is this getting fixed? It is super inconvenient having to search through many pages of messages manually.